# component doesn't render after mergin two APIS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render

After I request two endpoints and store it in a new state variable I'm not being able to render the component after the state changes. When i assign the state variable to the dependency array of useEffect it renders infinitely.

I tried a few things but the only way that i've being able to do to render the component after it loads has been just adding the merge state to the dependency array.

```
import { ChangeEvent, FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import spacex from "../api/spacex";
import CardGrid from "../components/CardGrid";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination";
import SkeletonGrid from "../components/SkeletonGrid";

type Launch = {
    mission_name: string;
};

const LaunchesMain: FC = () => {
    const [launches, setLaunches] = useState<any>([]);
    const [rockets, setRockets] = useState<any>([]);
    const [merged, setMerged] = useState([]);
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage, setPostsPerPage] = useState(9);
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
    const [filteredResult, setFilteredResult] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchRockets = async () => {
            const responseRocket = await spacex.get("/rockets");
            const responseLaunches = await spacex.get("/launches");

            setRockets(responseRocket.data);
            setLaunches(responseLaunches.data);
        };
        fetchRockets().then(() => {
            const mergedApis = () => {
                const launchesCopy: any = [...launches];

                for (let i = 0; i < launches.length; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < rockets.length; j++) {
                        if (launches[i].rocket.rocket_name === rockets[j].rocket_name) {
                            launchesCopy[i].rocket = rockets[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                setMerged(launchesCopy);
                setIsLoading(false);
            };
            mergedApis();
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(merged);

    const handleSearchChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);

        if (searchTerm.length === 0) {
            setFilteredResult(merged);
        } else if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
            const filteredData = merged.filter((launch: Launch) => {
                return `${launch.mission_name}`
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
            });
            setFilteredResult(filteredData);
        }
    };

    const lastPostIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const firstPostIndex = lastPostIndex - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = merged.slice(firstPostIndex, lastPostIndex);

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className="text-white">
                <div>
                    <input
                        style={{
                            background:
                                "linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)), #121212",
                        }}
                        onChange={(event) => handleSearchChange(event)}
                        placeholder="Search all launches..."
                        value={searchTerm}
                        className="md:w-[26rem] w-[16rem] h-[3rem] rounded-lg mt-10 mx-5 md:mx-24 rounded-3"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mx-5 md:ml-24 mt-5 opacity-40">
                    Total({currentPosts.length})
                </div>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <SkeletonGrid cards={postsPerPage} />
                ) : (
                    <CardGrid
                        postsData={currentPosts}
                        filteredResult={filteredResult}
                        searchTerm={searchTerm}
                    />
                )}

                <Pagination
                    totalPosts={merged.length}
                    postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
                    setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default LaunchesMain;
```

This is the code of the component. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need `rockets` and `launches` as a dependency of the `useEffect`, whenever they change, the `useEffect` is called, which calls the api, which changes, etc... However, you don't use `rockets` and `launches` states beyond merging them, and then you use the `merged` state.

So you don't have to store `rockets` and `launches` in the state. Use `Promise.all()` to get both data arrays in to `.then()` block, merge them, and store only the `merged` state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchRockets = () => Promise.all(
    spacex.get("/rockets"),
    spacex.get("/launches")
  ])
  
  fetchRockets()
    .then(([responseRocket, responseLaunches]) => {
      const rockets = responseRocket.data;
      const launches = responseLaunches.data;

      for (let i = 0; i < launches.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < rockets.length; j++) {
          if (launches[i].rocket.rocket_name === rockets[j].rocket_name) {
            launches[i].rocket = rockets[j];
          }
        }
      }

      setMerged(launches);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
}, []);
```